# Selenium cant find class to iterate and scrape text

Tags: python, selenium, class, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

as you can see in the first picture, my objective is to click and open every "Ver detalles" and to get all the text within it (which is shown in the third picture.

[image]

Here is the HTML for this first screen:

[image]
[image]
And here is the screen that opens once you click "ver detalles"

[image]
And its HTML

[image]

So far this I have made up some lines of code but I know it is useless because I am looking by XPATH and not by Class (and this will only return data for one), but whenever I look by class and try to iterate it doesn't find the class.

Please let me know if I made myself clear. Thanks beforehand

EDIT:

Thanks @cruisepandey it helped me open "ver detalles". Now I'm stucked trying to get the text out of it and click de X to close it and move on to the next "ver detalles".

This is the code I have so far, i have tried looking up by class, tag, etc but can't seem to find a way :(.

```
def order_data():

list_of_ver_detalles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Ver detalle')]/..")

sleep(3)
for ver in list_of_ver_detalles:
    ver.click()
    print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("jss672").text)
    sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[6]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/img[1]").click
```

Here is the text I am trying to print
[image]

And here is the X I am trying to click
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to clarify few of your doubts when you say **it is useless because I am looking by XPATH and not by Class** - no it is not. for finding more than one element with any locator (assuming that `locator in DOM can represent multiple entity`) all you have to do is to use `find_elements` instead of `find_element`.

store all of `Ver detalle` like this :

```
list_of_ver_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Ver detalle')]/..")
for ver in list_of_ver_links: 
    ver.click()
    #Now write the code to fetch order details here
```

Comment: Hello @cruisepandey , thanks for you help this worked, I added a new edit. Im not sure what i am doing wrong because I cant find elements by class, xpath or anything. I put both cases in my code and none working. Can you think of why they are not working?:(

Comment: @Darkoder : How can I login ? do you have global creds ? I have given below code to fetch details.. try it out

Comment: `texts = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@xpath='1']/descendant::p/span")
 for txt in texts: 
   print(txt.text)`

Comment: how can i message you privately to send credentials